# WWindow::operator HWND() { return _hwnd; }

Tags: c++, overloading

I do understand how to overload operators, but, obviously, not fully.

Can someone please explain the usage of the part

```
WWindow::operator HWND()
{
    // This overloaded operator allows us to use HWND anyway we want
    return _hwnd;
}
```

for me?

I don't understand how

```
operator HWND(){ ... }
```

is supposed to work?

Comment: You can pass `Window` instance to any function which accepts `HWND` parameter.

Answer (score 6):

This is an automatic conversion operator. The general prototype is:

```
operator TYPE();
```

That is, without the return type, as it must be the same type you are converting to.

This operator will be called whenever you use your original object (type `WWindow`) where a `HWND` is needed.

Note that usually it is a good idea to make conversion operators `const`:

```
operator HWND() const { ... }
```

but that depends on what you want it exactly to do with it.

Also, if you use C++11, you can declare them as explicit:

```
explicit operator HWND() const { ... }
```

so that it will not be called automatically in arbitrary contexts, but only in a few, safer situations, such as with `static_cast<HWND>(w)` or `HWND h(w)`, but not in `DestroyWindow(w)`.